# locks when updating a table with a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table (T1) with a trigger after update. This trigger looks for some values and then it updates other table (T2)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t1_AIR AFTER UPDATE ON t1 FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    v_dF1       DATE;
    v_dF2       DATE;
    v_nDays     NUMBER;
    v_cReg      VARCHAR2(50);

BEGIN

IF :NEW.BN_BE_ESTADO not in ('PEN', 'ERR', 'BAJ') THEN

    v_nDays := F_GET_PARAM(NULL, NULL, 'X_DAYS');

    PCK_AUX.PR_GET_F1(:NEW.F_A, v_dF1, v_cReg);
    PCK_AUX.PR_GET_F2(:NEW.F_A, v_dF2);

    UPDATE T2
    SET F_F1 = TRUNC(v_dF1),
        F_F2 = TRUNC(v_dF2),
        F_F_END = PCK_AUX.FU_GET_F_END(v_dF2+1, v_nDays),
        F_N_REG = v_cReg
    WHERE F_ID = :NEW.F_B;

END IF;

EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
         NULL;                   
END;
```

But when I update T1 it generates locks in both tables (t1 and t2)... does anyone know why??

Thanks to all

Comment: your trigger on t1 updates t2; so you are in the same situation of an update on t1 followed by an explicit update on t2

Comment: But t1 is updated by many apps, I thought it was easier with the trigger...

Comment: what type of lock is created?

Comment: @user2463409 it's easier in the sense that you only have to write the code in one place, but it cannot avoid locking rows that it needs to update.

Comment: You have an autonomous transaction block that performs DML but doesn't commit, so I'm surprised you aren't getting _ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back_. (Perhaps you are but it's being caught by your exception hider. The first thing I would do is remove both.)

Comment: I hadn't before the post, but i had the same error... i put it to try...

Answer (score 3):

When you update a table, row-level(TX) lock and table lock in row-share(RM) and row exclusive mode(RX) are acquired.

Row-level lock is there so other sessions couldn't modify row(s) being updated. Table locks in different modes are there to protect your table structure from modifications while DML statement (`update` in your case) in progress.

So yes, in your situation rows that are being updated will be locked in both `table 1 and table 2` plus table lock will be held in row share and row exclusive mode.

A bit about your trigger...

Why `autonomous transaction` pragma is there? Unless you are using that trigger for logging for example, situation when you have to commit whether main transaction succeeds or not, you really do not need this pragma. As @William Robertson absolutely correctly pointed out if use `autonomous transaction` you have to commit this autonomous transaction otherwise `ORA-06519` will be raised.

Reconsider usage of `when others then null` statement - would be better not to hide but re-raise any exceptions that might be generated.